# Castrated pet ownership

Tags: animals, ownership

Is it allowed to own a pet that was previous castrated by a non-jew without consent? Practical exemple: a well-behaved female dog adopted by a Jewish family after the castration (and adopted regardless the castration)

Answer (score 8):

[Rambam Hilchot Issurei Biah 16:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.16.13?lang=bi)

> אָסוּר לוֹמַר לְעַכּוּ''ם לְסָרֵס בְּהֵמָה שֶׁלָּנוּ. וְאִם לְקָחָהּ הוּא מֵעַצְמוֹ וְסֵרְסָהּ מֻתָּר. וְאִם הֶעֱרִים יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּדָבָר זֶה קוֹנְסִין אוֹתוֹ וּמוֹכְרָהּ לְיִשְׂרָאֵל אַחֵר
>
> It is forbidden to ask a non-Jew to castrate an animal of ours. But if he [the non-Jew] took it himself and castrated it, it [i.e keeping the animal] is permitted. But if the Jew connived in the matter, we fine him [by ruling that] he sell it to another Jew.

(Translation/elucidation is mine.)

Comment: Very nice; + 1.

Comment: This is not how we hold lema'ase

Comment: @Noach Care to amplify? (And who is we? Yemenites?)

Comment: @JoelK most Orthodox communities in the US

Comment: @Noach So how do “we” hold lema’ase?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt If you mean the more Yeshivish communities, they don’t take pets to begin with. If you mean the more modern communities, I don’t know of a single one in which this Rambam is not held of.